# Aggregate results in one row

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have table in SQL Server database with following structure.

**DB version:
DBMS: Microsoft SQL Server (ver. 12.00.5409)**

comments:

```
id | content | parent_id
```

And I would like to write a query that returns grouped child comments as a single row in main query.

So output will be like:

```
id | content | child_comments

1  | ''      | "[{id: 12, content: ""}, {id: 15, content: ""}, {id: 25, content: ""}]"
8  | ''      | "[{id: 22, content: ""}, {id: 44, content: ""}, {id: 65, content: ""}]"
```

I tried so far to create the following query

```
SELECT *,
       (SELECT * FROM comments c1 WHERE c.id = c1.parent_id GROUP BY c.parent_id)
FROM comments c
```

But of course I have the following error:

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list

In PostgreSQL I could use one of the available aggregating functions like "ARRAY_AGG". But I see in SQL Server db it's not possible to do it.

And unfortunately I can't modify that table at all.

Is there any way how I can achieve desired output format?

Thank you

Comment: In (fully) supported versions of SQL Server, JSON support is available natively. Considering that 2014 reaches EoL this year then upgrading seems like a viable solution here.

Comment: *In PostgreSQL I could use one of the available aggregating functions* The same would be true for SQL Server were you to be using an up-to-date version.

Comment: I can't modify server version.

Comment: As a side note, as far as I can tell, there is no 12.0.5409 build for SQL Server. There was a 12.0.5223.6, and then the next one was 12.0.5511.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately SQL Server doesn't support `JSON_ARRAYAGG` yet, although it is coming at some point.

But you don't need it. In *modern* versions of SQL Server (newer than your ancient SQL 2014), you can just use `FOR JSON` in your subquery.

```sql
SELECT *,
  (
    SELECT
      child.*
    FROM comments child
    WHERE c.id = child.parent_id
    FOR JSON PATH
  ) AS child_comments
FROM comments c;
```

In SQL Server 2014  you would have to concatenate and escape everything correctly yourself, as there is no native support for JSON.

Something like this maybe. Use `CONCAT` to get each row, the `FOR XML` trick to concatenate multiple rows, use `.value` to unescape the XML, and use `STUFF` to strip off the first comma.

```sql
SELECT *,
  '[' + STUFF((
    SELECT
      CONCAT(
        ',{"id":',
        child.id,
        ',"content":"',
        REPLACE(child.content, '"', '\"'),
        '"}'
      )
    FROM comments child
    WHERE c.id = child.parent_id
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
  ).value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '') + ']' AS child_comments
FROM comments c;
```